# May I drop "is" in constructions like "as is shown by the example of..."?

Tags: ellipsis, grammaticality-in-context

May I drop "is" in constructions like "as is shown by the example of..."?

On the one hand, such reduced variants can be met even in Wikipedia. But on the other hand, I don't quite understand its grammatical structure.

Comment: Rather, "as is shown by" is an "expanded" variant! The verb "is" is superfluous in the construction you present, and so is not omitted in "as shown by the example." This is a common and proper use of **as** in its rôle as an adverb with the meaning "in the manner." E.g.: _She sang as promised. He left as agreed._

Comment: Isn't it just a regular passive voice? "The body's  mass is constant as was established by Newton" One cannot replace "at" here by "in the manner", I think

Comment: The clause is in the passive voice, yes. "Was" could be seen as similarly superfluous in that example. I wouldn't write it this way, but I wouldn't mind reading _The body's mass is constant **in the manner** established by Newton._ @StoneyB may like to weigh in here, though, because _as_ is a contentious little fellow. He may make the case for an ellipsis of "is." (Also, the comma is our friend here: _The body's mass is constant, **in the manner** established by Newton._ )

Comment: @P.E.Dant *nudge* your comments seem to be enough for an answer and the upvotes on this question indicate some interest in it.

Comment: @ColleenV Nudge acknowledged. When time permits, I shall expand my comment into an answer, which will subsequently be debunked as utter hokum by StoneyB.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Lol, just mind your Ps and Qs when comes to the liguistical vocabulistics and we should be fine.

Comment: Never trust any sentence you find on Wikipedia to be grammatically correct. Most of them are, but there are many that are horrendous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than being a *reduced* variant, *as is shown by* in your example "as is shown by the example of" is an *expanded* variant!

The verb **is** is superfluous in the construction you present, and so is not omitted in *as shown by the example.* This is a common and proper use of *as* in its rôle as an adverb with the meaning "in the manner." See [Dictionary.com, definition 4:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as?s=t) *She sang as promised. He left as agreed.*

Your example phrase could thus be written as:

> *...in the manner/as* <s>is</s> shown by the example of...

In commentary, you suggested another example:

> The body's mass is constant *as was* established by Newton.

Likewise, "was" is superfluous here, and the sentence could be written as:

> The body's mass is constant *in the manner/as* <s>was</s> established by Newton.

It may be possible to make the case for an ellipsis of the verb "is" (as your question suggests) but many writers prefer a solution which uses the fewest words.

p.s.: The comma clarifies the meaning of either usage:

> The body's mass is constant, in the manner established by Newton.
>   The body's mass is constant, as (was) established by Newton.