# Use of As "in the manner"

Tags: prepositions, usage, conjunctions

I read this in [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as?s=t):

> **as** can mean **in the manner (directed, agreed, promised, etc.)**
>   *She sang as promised.*
>   *He left as agreed.*

I don't understand how **as** has been used **in the manner** in above sentences. Could you please make it clear to me? Is it the same as "Like agreed, like promised"?

Answer (score 1):

You are right: in this instance, **as** has the same meaning as **like**. Here are two references from a rather more reliable dictionary:

[as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as) - conjunction (LIKE) **in the same way**

[like](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like) - preposition, conjunction (SIMILAR TO) **in the same way** or manner as:

Note that, in expressions like **as agreed**, **as** is used as an adverb, not a conjunction. You will find more about this kind of usage [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102045/may-i-drop-is-in-constructions-like-as-is-shown-by-the-example-of/102276#102276).