# Which part is indispensable in constructions like "as it is illustrated..."?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, ellipsis

> - This conclusion can be verified by checking all the situations as *it is* illustrated in the appendix.

> - This conclusion can be verified by checking all the situations as *is* illustrated in the appendix.

> - This conclusion can be verified by checking all the situations as illustrated in the appendix.

There is a similar thread: [May I drop "is" in constructions like "as is shown by the example of..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102045/may-i-drop-is-in-constructions-like-as-is-shown-by-the-example-of)
But I was still confused. My question is: are all three sentences grammarly correct? Is "as" an adverb in all three sentences?

Comment: The third version is the most idiomatic. As explained in the other thread, **is** is superfluous here. The first version is incorrect.

Comment: The first version screams "Indian English" to me.

Comment: The third version "as illustrated" is the usual way to express this. The others are distinctly odd to me, although I would understand them.

Comment: Also google ngram agrees. [see here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+it+is+illustrated%2C+as+illustrated&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+is+illustrated%2Cas+illustrated&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: It's the situations not the conclusion that are illustrated, so you want "as they are illustrated" not "as it is illustrated". But in a technical document "as illustrated" is most common (or "(see illustrations)") - in other contexts you might use something different, which is why it helps to say what you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that any of these three forms are **wrong**. But the third is surely the most common in US English, at least in my experience.